# Rails Paginate Query with Subquery in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, kaminari

I have the following Postgres Query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT  100
   OFFSET 0
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT  100
OFFSET 0;
```

And I have converted it to an ActiveRecord query like so:

```
source_ids = '19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600, 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599'
subquery = Post.where('source_id = s.source_id AND deleted_at IS NULL')
           .order('external_created_at DESC')
Post.select('p.*')
 .from("unnest('{#{source_ids}}'::int[]) s(source_id), LATERAL (#{subquery.to_sql}) p")
 .order('p.external_created_at DESC')
```

I'd like to add Kaminari pagination to this.

The issue, however, is that for the query to work properly, I have to add the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to both the main query and the subquery.

If I just modify it like so:

```
source_ids = '19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600, 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599'
subquery = Post.where('source_id = s.source_id AND deleted_at IS NULL')
           .order('position, external_created_at DESC')
           .per(100).page(1)
Post.select('p.*')
 .from("unnest('{#{source_ids}}'::int[]) s(source_id), LATERAL (#{subquery.to_sql}) p")
 .order('p.position, p.external_created_at DESC')
 .per(100).page(1)
```

I get `undefined method 'per' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9682f540e0>`

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: Have you tried changing your last line to `.page(1).per(100)` ?  Note from the github page, 'Note that the per scope is not directly defined on the models but is just a method defined on the page scope' https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra yep that's it exactly. What a complicated question for a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might seem a little silly but have you tried calling `.page` before `.per` in your query? So `Post.where("...").order("...").page(1).per(100)`?

If that does not work, Kaminari can paginate arrays. Try converting your results into an array using `.to_a`, and then using the `paginate_array` helper method.

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object